# RayCast works only sometimes

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision, unityscript, raycasting

I am using ray cast to make get the collision. My player can move in all directions ( north , east , south and west)one step at a time but if an obstacle get into the way it will not move. For more clearance refer Crossy Road.

Detection of Obstacles if good sometimes but sometimes it dont get any collision and get into the obstacle.

I have rigidbody & collider attached to player and only colliders on obstacles.

[image: Properties of player]

### Code:-

```
         if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W))
         {
            PlayerScale = 1;
            this.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1,PlayerScale,1);
            
            if((Physics.Raycast(MidRay , Vector3.forward,out hit,2f)) ||(Physics.Raycast(LeftRay , Vector3.forward,out hit,2f))||(Physics.Raycast(RightRay , Vector3.forward,out hit,2f)) )
            {
                if(hit.collider.tag == "Obs")
                {
                    Debug.Log("CantMove");
                }
                else
                {
                    Score +=1;
                    TargetPos = new Vector3(this.transform.position.x,this.transform.position.y,this.transform.position.z+MoveDist);

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your `if` statement you got three or(||) it means if one of the three starting from the left returns true there is no need to check the rest because the whole statement is true , so lets assume `(Physics.Raycast(MidRay , Vector3.forward,out hit,2f))` is true and its `hit.collider.tag` isn't `obs` so it wont check the others and if your answer was in leftRay it will never be checked

Comment: I changed it to one condition and result is same.

Comment: you mean you wrote 4 If statement